# undefined behaviour while printing dynamic allocated array within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I'm supposed two data types, which contain a dynamically allocated array, and two variables `akt` and `max`, which indicate the position of the last element in the array and the length of the array respectively. Two functions should also be written, so that the first one adds new elements to the array, and reallocate the array in a doubled space if there's no enough space. the second function inserts also new elements into the array but it reallocates the array, such that its size is bigger by only one place.so my code goes like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

struct DynArray
{
    int *p, max, akt = 0;
};
struct DynArrayMin
{
    int *p, max, akt = 0;
};
void dyn_arr_add(struct DynArray* d, int x)
{
    if ((d->akt)>(d->max) - 1)
    {
        d->p = (int*)realloc(d->p, (d->max) * 2);
        d->max *= 2;
    }
    d->p[d->akt] = x;
    d->akt++;
}
void dyn_arr_min_add (struct DynArrayMin* d, int x)
{
    if ((d->akt)>(d->max) - 1)
    {
        d->p = (int*)realloc(d->p, (d->max) + 1);
        d->max++;
    }
    d->p[d->akt] = x;
    d->akt++;
}
void main()
{
    DynArray d;
    DynArrayMin e;
    int n, l, x,aa=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    d.max = n;
    d.p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    e.max = n;
    e.p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    do{
        printf("enter number\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        dyn_arr_add(&d, x);
        dyn_arr_min_add(&e, x);
        aa++;
        printf("want to enter another number; 0=no\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
    } while (l != 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < aa;i++)
    printf("%d%d\n", d.p[i], e.p[i]);
    free(e.p);
    free(d.p);
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

but starting with `n` = 5, which will be the initial size of the dynamically allocated arrays, and giving the numbers between 1 and 8 as an input, I was supposed to have an output like that:
    
    `11
    22
    33
    44
    55
    66
    77
    88`

but what i got was this pop-up message[this pop-up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99iaO.png), and the following output after clicking "continue" in the pop-up message: 

    `11
    2-842203134
    -33751037-33686019
    -1414791683-1414812757
    -1414812757-1414812757
    66
    77
    88`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `malloc` number of ints, but `realloc` number of bytes.

On the first calls to `realloc` that will make the buffer smaller, instead of larger.